# How to build deck starting in yard, ending on concrete slab?

Tags: deck, construction, decking

Here are some photos of my backyard with rough dimensions.

Needing help with how to end a deck from cemented posts in yard (at rear of house), to my back door. My trouble area is above the concrete.  Should I place a ledger board on house slab under siding and extend deck into yard on posts?  Or is there a way to not have to attach anything to the slab? Would also like it to run deck to the door to step out onto deck. From door threshold to cement slab is 6 inches.  Not sure on best approach here.  Thanks for any help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you dead set on a deck? A nice concrete patio might look sharp in this space, especially with all the stamping and coloring options available today.

Answer (score 1):

I think your goal should be to have the deck a couple of inches below the bottom of the siding. If you use 2x6 joists, you'll need 5.5" plus the width of the decking, so you'll have to dig out the grass enough to get that depth.

There are two ways to deal with the concrete pad.

1. You could put a 2x4 on it's side and shim it up with pressure-treated shims to get the height that you need. I'd attach it with Tapcon concrete screws.
2. You could tear out the concrete pad with an electric jackhammer.

When I did my deck, I tore out the pad. It was a fair bit of work, but the deck was a lot easier to build.

Comment: If I took your approach 1. How would you attach your frame and 16" spacer boards to an elevated 2x4? Wouldn't thisleave you only 2inches to attach your 2X6 runner boards? Thanks for your quick response.